# how do I get ContentControl to work in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

```
Sub FnWriteToWordDoc()
'
'Opens desired template to fill in data form range of cells
'Dim wApp As Word.Application
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
'Opens template to create document
Documents.Add Template:="M:\file.dotm"

'Below Tells to keep values in memory
Dim currentDay As String
Dim currentMonth As String
Dim currentYear As String
currentDay = Format(Now(), "dd")
currentMonth = Format(Now(), "mmm")
currentYear = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
Set wdApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
     If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     End If
strDocName = "C:\Document\sample.docx"
Dim cc As wdApp.ContentControl ' Error Here

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("monthName")
    cc.Title = currentMonth
Next
```

I get an error saying

```
Compile error:
User-defined type not defined
```

The Function is located within "Sheet1" under the Folder called "Microsoft Excel Objects". I had the same code in the "Modules1" and moved.

I am trying to get Excel to insert into my Word document content controls.

Comment: Try changing `For Each cc In ActiveDocument...` to `For Each cc In wdApp.ActiveDocument...`

Comment: You never actually open strDocName, do so capturing the document then you can access documentVar.ContentControl**s**.

Comment: I think you need to set the name in the second argument to get the current instance: `GetObject(,"Word.Application")`.

Comment: `ActiveDocument` is not an object in Excel VBA - you need to scope that to the Word Application:  `wdApp.ActiveDocument`

Comment: I think I am creating a new document based on the dotm file. I never saved the new file but I should still be able to access the controls on the new document. Right? @VBobCat can you write that as an answer. I think I tried using ActiveDocument but I may not have expanded it enough. I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is error here

> ```
> Dim cc As wdApp.ContentControl
> ```
>
> because you need to enable the Microsoft Word 12 Library. Go to Tools>References and find Microsoft Word library and put a check mark next to it

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FnWriteToWordDoc()
    '
    'Opens desired template to fill in data form range of cells

    Dim wApp As Object
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim wDoc As Object
    Set wDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Opens template to create document
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="M:\file.dotm")

    'Below Tells to keep values in memory
    Dim currentDay As String
    Dim currentMonth As String
    Dim currentYear As String
    currentDay = Format(Now(), "dd")
    currentMonth = Format(Now(), "mmm")
    currentYear = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
    strDocName = "C:\Document\sample.docx"

    ' you must declare your variable with class' name, not instanced object's name
    Dim cc As Object        

    For Each cc In wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("monthName")
        cc.Range.Text = currentMonth
    Next
```

The code above is functional code and is able to write into the ContentControls. Thanks to VBobCat for his inspiration

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I believe this could work:

```
Sub FnWriteToWordDoc()
    '
    'Opens desired template to fill in data form range of cells

    Dim wApp As Word.Application 'declare empty variable
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document  'declare empty variable
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' get instance
        If wApp Is Nothing Then 'getting existing instance failed
            Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'create new instance
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    wApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Opens template to create document
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:="M:\file.dotm") 'get instance of document

    'Below Tells to keep values in memory
    Dim currentDay As String
    Dim currentMonth As String
    Dim currentYear As String
    currentDay = Format(Now(), "dd")
    currentMonth = Format(Now(), "mmm")
    currentYear = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
    strDocName = "C:\Document\sample.docx"

    ' you must declare your variable with class' name, not instanced object's name
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

    For Each cc In wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("monthName")
        cc.Title = currentMonth
    Next

    wDoc.SaveAs2 strDocName
    wDoc.Close False

    If wApp.Documents.Count = 0 Then wApp.Quit False
End Sub
```

Comment: Same error. It thinks Word.ContentControl is a custom type

Comment: @softwareisfun `Word.ContentControl` **is** a custom type.  Do you have the `Microsoft Word vv.v Object Library` reference ticked so that it can refer to that custom type?  If not, declare your object `As Object`.

Comment: How do I reference it? Are you asking me to declare my content control (cc) as Object?

Comment: @softwareisfun, in your VBA window, click menu Tools > References and you can see all COM references registered in your system. Most of them are not ment to be accessed from VBA, but those from MS Office programs are interoperable. When you mark that of Microsoft Word, you'll have access to the object model of MS-Word. Just remember you are still in Excel's namespace, so you must fully qualify your word "foreign" objects.

Comment: @softwareisfun, if you want to make edits to update the code you are using, they should be made to your question, not to my answer ;-)